# Onchange event used with jquery slider

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a jquery slider add-on that when it is manipulated, it writes the value to a linux file.

The Slider controls a text input box. The box is readonly, so it is always blurred. The problem I can't understand is why the onchange command will not work. If I remove the readonly attribute on my input command, I run into the same problem.

I know that my javascript function works, because I can change the value of the text input box and press enter and it will update. But what I need it to do is to update the number whenever the slider changes it, so I can't use the keyup or keydown command, because a slider controls it, not the user's input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#LeftRecordSlider" ).slider({

        range: "min",

        orientation: "vertical",

        value: 50,

        min: 0,

        max: 100,

        slide: function( event, ui ) {

            $( "#LeftRecordAmount" ).val( ui.value );

        }

    });

    $( "#LeftRecordAmount" ).val( $( "#LeftRecordSlider" ).slider( "value" ) );

});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ChangeVolume(volumetype,volumelevel)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {//IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {//IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("VolumeOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ChangeVolume.php?volumetype="+volumetype+"&volumelevel="+volumelevel,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        };



</script>


<label for="LeftRecordAmount">Left Record Volume:</label>

<input type="text" onchange="ChangeVolume('LeftRecord',this.value)" id="LeftRecordAmount" style="border:0; width:3em; color:#0080ff; font-weight:bold;" readonly/>

<div id="VolumeOutput"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call event or method explicit. Follow the below approaches

```
$( "#LeftRecordSlider" ).slider({
    range: "min",
    orientation: "vertical",
    value: 50,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#LeftRecordAmount").val( ui.value );
    },
    stop : function(event, ui){
        eval($("#LeftRecordAmount").attr("onchange")); // first approach
        ChangeVolume('LeftRecord',ui.value) // second approach
    }

});
```

User any of them.

Comment: Works perfect. I think my only change I'm going to make is to move the eval($("#LeftRecordAmount").attr("onchange")); to the slide portion. I'll have to evaluate to see if the change is worth it or if it will bog down the site too much. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pr-, well i used it because when the slider event get stopped you will do what the function requires. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Good point. I guess it seems like a waste of bandwidth. This is an internal site, but the constant changes might replicate a dos attack. Looks like I'll stick with your original code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Holy white-space batman hopefully your code doesn't actually like that your increasing parsing times a lot. Also I don't understand why you're not using the Ajax method included in jQuery library why reinvent the wheel when it already supports back to IE6. Another thing Java and JavaScript are two entirely different things please don't reference them the same. As for the readonly textbox why don't you just use the disabled property instead it works much better. This also might be a better approach.

```
  var control = document.getElementById("LeftRecordAmount");
  control.addEventListener("change", function(){
      //do whatever here
  }
  //vanilla javascript runs faster than jQuery you can even test with console.time() profiler and        jsperf.com
  //inline handlers are also bad here's why
```

http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter4.html